# How do I prove that this extension is integral?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, localization

Let $A$ be an integral domain, let $K$ be its field of fractions, and let $L$ be a finite extension of $K$. For a $\alpha \in L$, let $B=A[\alpha]$. Prove that exists a non-zero $a\in A$ such that the extension $A_a \subseteq B_a$ is integral.

Note: $A_a = S^{-1}A = \{m/n : m\in A, n\in S \}$,
$S = \{1,a, a^2, a^3,...\}$. (Same for $B_a$)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean this extension is *integral*?  Did you mean *an integral domain*?

Comment: would help if you told us the textbook you are using, or a link to the lecture notes.

Comment: I'm using the notes made by my professor and I cannot give you a link but it doesn't say anything too specific . This is part of a work that I'm allowed to complete using bibliography of any kind, by the way. Pd: yes I think it's an integral domain and the extension is integral. Sorry for that, I'm not used to do math in english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Take the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. Consider the product of all denominators in the coefficients. This will give you a localization where $\alpha$ is integral, and that's sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I really appreciate it. However, I don't really understand how that is sufficient. Basically, I don't see why the fact that $\alpha$ is integral makes all the elements $a+\alpha *b$ integral in $A_a$.

Comment: Integral elements are closed under sums and products. If you are having that exercise this must have been covered before. PS: what you describe are not all elements in $A[\alpha]$.

Comment: That's right, I just read it. Thank you so much again for the help